# MySQL and MariaDB report no strings containing ampersand when I can SEE them in the database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Because of an old programming error I have a bunch of records in my database which contain values such as:

```
"https://central.bac-lac.gc.ca/.item/?app=Census1901&op=&img&id=z000058993"
```

when they should contain:

```
"https://central.bac-lac.gc.ca/.item/?app=Census1901&op=img&id=z000058993"
```

I tried to replace them by

```
UPDATE Pages SET image=replace(image, '&img','img')  where locate('&img', image) > 0
```

But MySQL and MariaDB report that NO values contain '&img'.  For example if I issue:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pages where locate('&img', image) > 0
```

it returns zero records.  When I list the records I can SEE that there are thousands of records containing the mistake but MySQL and MariaDB insist that they do not exist?  If I remove the WHERE clause:

```
UPDATE Pages SET image=replace(image, '&img','img')
```

the server insists that it could not find any values to change.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not reproduced. https://dbfiddle.uk/E3rIW30S I think that the value STORED is not one which you SEE - due to client "service". Look using CLI. Maybe even in HEX(). PS. `where locate('&img', image)` is enough, `> 0` is excess.

Comment: Yes, please edit your question to show output of `select hex(image) from Pages where ...` looking at the row whose value you show.

Answer (score 1):

I think the ampersands (&) in your database could be stored as `&amp;` (since HTML encode). You should try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pages WHERE LOCATE('&amp;img', image) > 0;` to confirm it.